# Angular 5 and slide up animation

Tags: angular

I'm creating an animation that changes(slides up) element height to 0 and returns it to initial height. Why element returns to initial height after 'hide' animation. does anyone know how to fix this? Also element height is changing by media queries. Link to project: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzbwnc

Animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger("myAnimationTrigger", [
     transition('hide => show', [
      style({ height: '0', opacity: 0 }), 
      animate('1500ms', style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition('show => hide', [
        style({ height: '*', opacity: 1 }),
        animate('1500ms', style({ height: '0px', opacity: 0 })),
      ]),
    ])
  ]
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzbwnc

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your StackBlitz work by changing your animation code to the following:

```js
trigger("myAnimationTrigger", [
  state('show', style({
      'max-height': '300px', 'opacity': '1'
  })),
  state('hide', style({
      'max-height': '0px', 'opacity': '0'
  })),
  transition('hide => show', [
    animate('1500ms', style({ 'max-height': '300px', 'opacity': '1' })),
  ]),
  transition('show => hide', [
    animate('1500ms', style({ 'max-height': '0px', 'opacity': '0' })),
  ])
])
```

Comment: It works, but what if ul container is dynamically chanding, by media-queries?